# How to implement my own loss function for Prototype learning using Keras Model

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, loss-function, meta-learning

I'm trying to migrate this code, "[Omniglot Character Set Classification Using Prototypical Network](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Meta-Learning-with-Python/blob/master/Chapter03/3.3%20Omniglot%20Character%20set%20classification%20using%20Prototypical%20Network.ipynb)", into Tensorflow 2.1.0 and Keras 2.3.1.

My problem is about how to use euclidean distance between train data and validation data. Look at this code:

```
def convolution_block(inputs, out_channels, name='conv'):

    conv = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding='SAME')
    conv = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv, updates_collections=None, decay=0.99, scale=True, center=True)
    conv = tf.nn.relu(conv)
    conv = tf.contrib.layers.max_pool2d(conv, 2)

    return conv


def get_embeddings(support_set, h_dim, z_dim, reuse=False):

    net = convolution_block(support_set, h_dim)
    net = convolution_block(net, h_dim)
    net = convolution_block(net, h_dim) 
    net = convolution_block(net, z_dim) 
    net = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(net)

    return net



support_set_embeddings = get_embeddings(tf.reshape(support_set, [num_classes * num_support_points, img_height, img_width, channels]), h_dim, z_dim)

embedding_dimension = tf.shape(support_set_embeddings)[-1]

class_prototype = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reshape(support_set_embeddings, [num_classes, num_support_points, embedding_dimension]), axis=1)

query_set_embeddings = get_embeddings(tf.reshape(query_set, [num_classes * num_query_points, img_height, img_width, channels]), h_dim, z_dim, reuse=True)


def euclidean_distance(a, b):

    N, D = tf.shape(a)[0], tf.shape(a)[1]
    M = tf.shape(b)[0]
    a = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(a, axis=1), (1, M, 1))
    b = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(b, axis=0), (N, 1, 1))
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(a - b), axis=2)


distance = euclidean_distance(query_set_embeddings,class_prototype)

predicted_probability = tf.reshape(tf.nn.log_softmax(-distance), [num_classes, num_query_points, -1])

loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(y_one_hot, predicted_probability), axis=-1), [-1]))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.to_float(tf.equal(tf.argmax(predicted_probability, axis=-1), y)))

train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
```

If I have understood everything correctly, it get the embeddings from the `support_set` (aka training data), and the embeddings from the `query_set` (aka validation data). Compute the mean for all the embeddings from the `support_set`, because all of them are from the same class. Then, it uses this mean to compute the distance between the embeddings from the `query_set` and this mean (aka `class_prototype`).

So, if I want to use VGG16 as the `get_embeddings` function. In other words, I'm going to use it to get the embeddings for the `support_set` and `query_set`:

```
def vgg16_feature_extractor(input_size = (200,200,1)):
    inputs = Input(input_size, name = 'input')

    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv1_1')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv1_2')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_1')(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv2_1')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv2_2')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_2')(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_1')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_2')(conv3)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_3')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_3')(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_1')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_2')(conv4)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_3')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_4')(conv4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_1')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_2')(conv5)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_3')(conv5)
    pool5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_5')(conv5)

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = pool5, name = 'vgg-16_feature_extractor')

    return model
```

And, then on `train.py`:

```
model = vgg16_feature_extractor(input_size = (200,200,1))
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=my_own_loss_function, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(...)
```

I don't know how to implement the `my_own_loss_function`, because this function will have only two parameters `y_true, y_pred` and the `y_pred` has to been calculated using the euclidean distance between `support_set` embeddings and `query_set` embeddings.

How do I have to implement the `my_own_loss_function` to use it as I want?

Maybe, `y_true` are the embeddings from `support_set` and `y_pred` are the embeddings from `query_set`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are several ways you can do that.

A quite powerful solution is to define a pred layer

```
class PredLayer(Layer):
    """
        Layer object to calculate distance between query_embeddings and supposrt embeddings.
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PredLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def euclidean_distance(self, inputs):
        """
            Euclidean square distance.
        """
        support, query = inputs
        output = K.mean(K.square(support - query), axis=-1)
        output = K.expand_dims(output, 1)
        return output

    def call(self, inputs):
        y_pred = self.euclidean_distance(inputs)
        return y_pred
```

Hence you have to compose your Keras network such that your support and query embeddings will be the inputs to this layer.

````
...

model_pred = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = predlayer, name = 'vgg-16_feature_extractor_pred')

return model, model_pred
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I do it, can I use this network to predict?

Comment: Well the model_pred does exactly this. after calling the function call `model.layers` and `model_pred.layers` to check they share all the layers but the last one, and then yes. Training one will mean training the second.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is not what I need. I need to train the network using support_set as training data, and query_set as validation_data. And then, use this trained network to predict the class of an unseen example. Thanks a lot.